# How to get a partial regression plot in R?

Tags: r, regression, statistical-test

| Cow | Western | Ashely | Jerzy |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 24.3 | 34.3 | 50 | 45 |
| 30.2 | 35.3 | 54 | 45 |
| 49 | 45 | 540 | 4353 |
| 70 | 60 | 334 | 343 |
| 69 | 80 | 54 | 342 |

I looked up online and in couple books regarding this however I couldn't find a helpful information. Could you just give me a sample of how to find partial plots and also matrix diagonals vs observation number

Comment: Can you describe more what you mean by "matrix diagonals vs observation number"?

Comment: And partial regression plots generally have a regression associated with them. Do you have a model? Have you decided what variables are predictors and what is your outcome? I think it would help this question a lot if you showed at least a little bit of what you've tried, and could be more specific about your goals.